# Looking for RDLC designer run at Web browser

Tags: reporting-services, designer, rdlc, report, rdl

My customer asked me that is possible to provide a designer for edit RDLC/RDL file in the Web, I used [Stimulsoft](http://www.stimulsoft.com/) report before, i know it allow user edit their report online,and it use Flex and Silverlight implemented the designer.

But it can not using for RDL or RDLC format report,i think it's very useful for end-user edit RDLC report, i found the [fyireporting designer](http://www.fyireporting.com/products.html) ,but it only working for Winform.

RDLC Web Designer,I think it's an interesting subject.

Some one can Help me?

Comment: just as a side note, you can use winforms with mvc they work nicely together (if no other choice)